# Screen reader: adding additional text for screen reader into selectbox

Tags: html, class, drop-down-menu, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

How to add a text **for screen reader only** so that it is pronounced

```
Volvo selected, Saab selected, Mercedes selected, Audi selected
```

instead of

```
Volvo, Saab, Mercedes, Audi
```

respectively. Adding

```
<span class="sr-only">selected</span>
```

into

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

doesn't help.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARIA labels are your solution, yes. However, you shouldn't do this in any way.
the info about what is selected and what is not is provided by screen reader itself. More than that, if you design a multi-select list box (i.e., with a `multiple` attribute), and your user enters the box and presses `Shift+F8`, he/she will hear something like this:

Volvo selected selected
Saab selected selected

This is really, really annoying, believe me. So just don't bother with it and provide a standard accessible (multi-select, if needed) list box.

Answer (score 1):

ARIA text and labels can solve this and provide information for a screen reader. 
For example the following would label the letter 'x' as being a close button.

```
<button aria-label="Close" onclick="myDialog.close()">X</button>
```

The above example comes from here: [Aria Label Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute)

Read more about other [ARIA roles, attributes, and techniques](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques).

Comment: This is about buttons. What about select boxes?